# Spring Oauth2 - update to 2.0.x and configuration no longer works

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

Ok, so, after updating to Spring Oauth2 2.0.6 - from 1.0.0.M6, my configuration stopped working. I had to make a few tweaks here and the (like, some classes that no longer exists and some that changed package).

The current configuration is the following one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-2.0.xsd">

    <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />

    <http pattern="/favicon.ico" security="none" />
    <http pattern="/login/**" security="none" />
    <http pattern="/css/**" security="none" />
    <http pattern="/js/**" security="none" />
    <http pattern="/img/**" security="none" />
    <http pattern="/mockdata/**" security="none" />
    <http pattern="/p/api/**" security="none" />

    <http pattern="/p/public/**" entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager">
        <intercept-url pattern="/p/public/**" access="ROLE_OAUTH_CLIENT" />
        <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="EXCEPTION_TRANSLATION_FILTER" />
    </http>

    <http pattern="/public/**" entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager">
        <intercept-url pattern="/public/**" access="ROLE_OAUTH_CLIENT" />
        <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="EXCEPTION_TRANSLATION_FILTER" />
    </http>

    <http pattern="/p/oauth/token" create-session="never" authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager">
        <intercept-url pattern="/p/oauth/token" access="ROLE_OAUTH_CLIENT" />
        <anonymous enabled="false" />
        <http-basic />
        <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    </http>

    <http access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager">
        <intercept-url pattern="/p/tasks/comment" access="ROLE_ACTIVE,ROLE_OAUTH_CLIENT" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ACTIVE"/>

        <!-- ATTENTION TO THIS LINE - If commented out the login works -->
        <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="EXCEPTION_TRANSLATION_FILTER" />

        <access-denied-handler error-page="/login/" />

        <form-login login-page="/login/" default-target-url="/" authentication-failure-url="/login/?error=1" />
        <http-basic/>
        <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/" />
        <remember-me user-service-ref="userDetailsServiceImpl" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsServiceImpl">
            <password-encoder hash="md5"/>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <beans:property name="realmName" value="on-tasks2" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />

    <beans:bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
        <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">
        <beans:constructor-arg>
            <beans:list>
                <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter" />
                <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter">
                    <beans:property name="rolePrefix" value="" />
                </beans:bean>
                <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
            </beans:list>
        </beans:constructor-arg>
    </beans:bean>

    <authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserDetailsService" />
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="clientDetailsUserDetailsService" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="tokenServices" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
        <beans:property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
        <beans:property name="supportRefreshToken" value="false" />
        <beans:property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="tokenStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JdbcTokenStore">
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
    </beans:bean>

    <oauth:authorization-server
        client-details-service-ref="clientDetails"
        token-services-ref="tokenServices"
        authorization-endpoint-url="/p/oauth/authorize"
        token-endpoint-url="/p/oauth/token"
        user-approval-page="access_confirmation">
        <oauth:authorization-code />
        <oauth:implicit />
        <oauth:refresh-token />
        <oauth:client-credentials />
        <oauth:password />

    </oauth:authorization-server>

    <oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter" resource-id="on-tasks" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />

    <beans:bean id="clientDetails" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.JdbcClientDetailsService">
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

With this configuration as-is, whenever I try to login, it redirects to the login page with a 302 code on **/j_spring_security_check**. If I comment that line (*custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="EXCEPTION_TRANSLATION_FILTER"*) out, the login works.

Also, now, if I try to access **localhost:8080/p/oauth/token?client_id=the-client-ids&client_secret=someMockedSecret&grant_type=client_credentials&scope=comment** I get a 404, whereas before it used to create the access token.

The lines that were changed with the update are the following:

```
-    <beans:bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.MediaTypeAwareAuthenticationEntryPoint">
+    <beans:bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">

-   <beans:bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.MediaTypeAwareAccessDeniedHandler" />
+   <beans:bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />

-   <beans:bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.filter.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
+   <beans:bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">

-   <beans:bean id="tokenServices" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.RandomValueTokenServices">
+   <beans:bean id="tokenServices" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">

-   <beans:bean id="tokenStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.JdbcTokenStore">
+   <beans:bean id="tokenStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JdbcTokenStore">

-   <beans:bean id="clientDetails" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.JdbcClientDetailsService">
+   <beans:bean id="clientDetails" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.JdbcClientDetailsService">
```

Any suggestions? I've tried a few different configurations that I found here in StackOverflow but none of them worked for me.

Thanks in any advance.

-glauber

Comment: Stupid question: is your app running on the root context (/)?

Comment: Hey @DaveSyer, yes but my dispatcher servlet is mapped to /p/*

Comment: I don't think you need to set the authorization-endpoint-url and oken-endpoint-url (you are using the defaults and /p is the servlet path).

Comment: Hey @DaveSyer, well I tried to change that but the result is the same..

Comment: You should see all the endpoint paths logged on startup. Is it there?